# Material design refresh icon change?

Tags: android, icons, material-design

I'm updating an app to have a more material design look and feel.  I have a refresh icon in my toolbar, and I'm wondering if this icon should change.  Looking at google's new icons here https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/navigation/drawable-hdpi/ic_refresh_grey600_36dp.png , it looks like it has changed.

But on their downloads page it has a different icon https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html.  This is the one I have been using and it has two arrows.  The new one just has one arrow.
Does anyone know if the one with one arrow is indeed the one google is switching to with material design?

Answer (score 1):

you are downloading the wrong resources, you are still downloading the HOLO resources. You want the material resources found here

http://www.google.com/design/spec/resources/sticker-sheets-icons.html

Comment: Your link leads me to the new icon with one arrow, so I guess that's your answer.  Also, it appears a lot smaller in the toolbar than the old one I think.

Comment: there are multiple sizes to the icon, once you download the resources you will see what I mean

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering about the exact same thing some few days back. I couldn't find a definite answer anywhere, but from what I could gather, the one that is posted [here](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/navigation/drawable-hdpi/ic_refresh_grey600_36dp.png), this is the latest one. If you see the latest Gmail android app, the refresh icon that comes up when you pull down, is the one with a single arrow. (and not 2 arrows)